# setOnFinished() infinite loop?

Tags: java, javafx-2

```
else {
    ScaleTransition st = new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(1000), gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
    st.setByX(-1f);
    st.setByY(-1f);
    System.out.println("Loop"); //loop signal
    st.play();

    st.setOnFinished(e-> {
        pane.getChildren().remove(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
        gameView[ex.row][ex.col]=null;
        scores.addAndGet(1);
    });
}
```

The code snippet above is part of my Match 3 game.The `gameView` is an `ArrayList` which stores the sprites to be removed from the pane, and outside of the `if-else` is a `foreach` loop. I want to make a scaling animation before removing the sprites, but it always runs into infinite loop.Why ?

Edit: Before i add the animation , my game can run smoothly. And if i don't call `setOnFinished()` my game still runs smoothly but without animation.

```
public static void remove(Buttonp[][] gameView,ArrayList<matrixLocator> removableButtonGroup,Pane pane,AtomicInteger scores){
    for(matrixLocator ex:removableButtonGroup){
        if(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]!=null){
            if(gameView[ex.row][ex.col].verticalExplosion==true){
                pane.getChildren().remove(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
                gameView[ex.row][ex.col]=null;
                scores.addAndGet(1);
                ArrayList<matrixLocator> al1=new ArrayList<matrixLocator>();
                for(int m=0;m<8;m++){
                    if((gameView[m][ex.col]!=null)&&(m!=ex.row)){
                        al1.add(new matrixLocator(m,ex.col));
                    }
                    else;
                }
                remove(gameView,al1,pane,scores);
            }
        //verticalExplosion
            else if(gameView[ex.row][ex.col].horizontalExplosion==true){
                pane.getChildren().remove(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
                gameView[ex.row][ex.col]=null;
                scores.addAndGet(1);
                ArrayList<matrixLocator> al2=new ArrayList<matrixLocator>();
                for(int m=0;m<10;m++){
                    if((gameView[ex.row][m]!=null)&&(m!=ex.col)){
                        al2.add(new matrixLocator(ex.row,m));
                    }
                    else;
                }
                remove(gameView,al2,pane,scores);
            }
        //horizontalExplosion
            else if(gameView[ex.row][ex.col].aroundExplosion==true){
                pane.getChildren().remove(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
                gameView[ex.row][ex.col]=null;
                scores.addAndGet(1);
                ArrayList<matrixLocator> al3=new ArrayList<matrixLocator>();
                for(int m=0;m<8;m++){
                    for(int n=0;n<10;n++){
                        if((Math.abs(m-ex.row)<=1)&&(Math.abs(n-ex.col)<=1)){
                            if((gameView[m][n]!=null)&&((m!=ex.row)||(n!=ex.col))){
                                al3.add(new matrixLocator(m,n));
                                }
                            else;
                        }
                        else;
                    }
                }
                remove(gameView,al3,pane,scores);
            }
        //aroundExplosion           
            else{
                ScaleTransition st=new ScaleTransition(Duration.millis(2000),gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
                st.setByX(-1f);
                st.setByY(-1f);
                System.out.println("LOOP");
                st.play();

                st.setOnFinished(e->{
                pane.getChildren().remove(gameView[ex.row][ex.col]);
                gameView[ex.row ][ex.col]=null;
                scores.addAndGet(1);});
               }    
            }
        else;
    }
}
```

this is the whole .
`Buttonp` is subclass of button and is given some properties. So it's the button(the sprites i called) 2-dimension array of my game.
`matrixLocator` is another class containing only two integers , row and column , to locate the button to be removed. 
Pane is my game pane .

Edit: I run a demo just now , and i found the problem shouldn't be the `setOnFinished()` but should be the `foreach` loop .But why the loop will go infinitely? 
And sorry for explaining the question not correctly and clearly.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without knowing the rest of the code (e.g. the loop). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the problem clearly. I tried to write a short demo to simulate the program above , but i failed to get into the infinite loop . So i decided to post the whole part . Hope you don't mind :).

Comment: Hmm, did you step through your code with a debugger? I can't see a problem on a glance.